# Wordpress Media Page lists only pictures of current user and administrator

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

It is possible, I list images of the current user and administrator, below is the code I am using.

It currently works normally for just the current user to list their images, but I wish the admin images could also be listed.

In other words, listing the images of the current user and the administrator, is it possible?

```
// Page media list only store images
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'attachments_wpquery_where' );
function attachments_wpquery_where( $where ) {
    global $current_user;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        // we spreken over een ingelogde user
        if( isset( $_POST['action'] ) ){
            // library query
            if( $_POST['action'] == 'query-attachments' ) {
                $where .= ' AND post_author='.$current_user->data->ID;
            }
        }
    }

    return $where;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed using this code, the conditional makes all the difference.

```
// Page media list only store images
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','users_own_attachments' );

function users_own_attachments( $wp_query_obj ) {
    global $current_user, $pagenow;

    if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) 
        return;
    
    if ( !is_a( $current_user, 'WP_User' ) )
        return;

    if ( ( 'edit.php' != $pagenow ) && ( 'upload.php' != $pagenow ) && ( ( 'admin-ajax.php' != $pagenow ) || ( $_REQUEST['action'] != 'query-attachments' ) ) )
        return;

    $author__in = array( $current_user->id, 1 );
    $wp_query_obj->set('author__in', $author__in );

    return;
}
```